# What happens if using glVertexAttribFormat for wrong type?

Tags: opengl

What happens if the version of `glVertexAttribFormat` doesnt match the data type in the shader?

Specs say:

> `glVertexAttribFormat` and `glVertexArrayAttribFormat` should be used to describe vertex attribute layout for floating-point vertex attributes, `glVertexAttribIFormat` and `glVertexArrayAttribIFormat` should be used to describe vertex attribute layout for integer vertex attribute.

But in the "Errors" section it doesn't say anything about using `glVertexAttribFormat` for integer types (type in the shader) or `glVertexAttribIFormat` for float types. Will it produce garbage data or will it be converted automatically?

Comment: You'll get garbage data

Comment: "*Specs say:*" I don't find that quote in the specification. If you're going to quote something, you should attribute it properly.

Comment: @NicolBolas OK. I thought this is specs but might not be:
https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribFormat.xhtml

Comment: No, this is just an online help and is not always complete, or sometimes inaccurate. The OpenGL specifications can be fount here: [Khronos OpenGL® Registry](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/index_gl.php)